# Hyperbolic orbit to keplerian orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, gravitational-waves, post-newtonian

How do I model a two body system that is initially travelling on an unbound orbit (hyperbolic so negative semi major axis) but then becomes a bound orbit (eccentric elliptic, so positive semi major axis). For example this may occur in a two body system emitting Gravitational Waves where the two body system is initially travelling on a hyperbolic orbit, but due to the energy and momentum extraction due to gravitational waves the bodies become bound.

The natural follow up question is then, how do I relate the hyperbolic orbital element to the keplerian elements in such a system?

Comment: If gravitational radiation is significant, I don’t think hyperbolic or elliptical orbits will be good approximations.

Comment: @G.Smith That is true, but suppose if the force is dynamical friction (or some other resistive force), then how would that be modelled?
Also the binary may be just hyperbolic, so GW wont need to be significant in order to change the binary to elliptic, right?

Comment: @G.Smith Even in the relativistic regime bound orbits are regularly described using (precessing) ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to parameterize the [Keplerian orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit) using the *eccentricity* $e$ and *semi-latus rectum* $p$ such that the orbit is given by

$$ r(\theta) = \frac{p}{1+e\cos\theta}. $$

With this parameterization, $e>1$ corresponds to hyperbolic orbits, and $0<e<1$ corresponds to elliptic orbit, and all orbits have finite $p$. Most importantly there is a smooth transition from the one regime to the other.

PS. Note that hyperbolic Keplerian orbits are still Keplerian orbits.